# White screen then scrolling uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Im using storyboards with prototypecells what looks like:[image]

after that im adding dynamic count of subviews:[image]

[white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBpMj.png)

[uitableviewcell in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hExVF.jpg)

Problem what sometimes white screen appears on half of uitableviewcell then scrolling.

And cell==nil not called.

Or just explain how to add dynamic count of subviews to uitableviewcell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifer;

    cellIdentifer = @"PhotoWorkCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSLog(@"is nil");
    }
    [self addSubviews:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];//just setting images and text to views

    return cell;
}

-(void)addSubviews:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    PhotoWork *work = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    PhotoWorkCell *workCell = (PhotoWorkCell*)cell;

    for(UIView *view in workCell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[CustomPoints class]])
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for(int i=0; i <[work.pointsArray count];i++)
    {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomPoints" owner:self options:nil];
        CustomPoints *customPoints = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        customPoints.frame = CGRectMake(10, 135+i*customPoints.frame.size.height, customPoints.frame.size.width, customPoints.frame.size.height);

        customPoints.label= @"test";

        workCell.photoButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [workCell.photoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onHistory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [workCell.contentView addSubview:customPoints];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoWork *work = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return 135+[work.pointsArray count]*57;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's documentation of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method:

*`This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.`*

This means that, if a cell with that identifier exists, the method will never return nil, but will rather initialise the cell for you through the initializer method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Then from the documentation of the `UITableViewCell`'s method `prepareForReuse`:

*`The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.`*

Which means that you should remove the additional subviews it might have before adding the new ones in your `addSubviews:atIndexPath:` method.

You could simply do:

```
NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:workCell.contentView.subviews];
```

Then, assuming that the only extra subview you add to contentView is this CustomPoints, just do:

```
[tmpArray removeObject:tmpArray.lastObject];
workCell.contentView.subviews = tmpArray;
```

If, instead, you want to be safe just do:

```
__block NSInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;
[tmpArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CustomPoints class]]) {
        foundIndex = idx;
        // stop the enumeration
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
if (foundIndex != NSNotFound){ 
    [tmpArray removeObjectAtIndex:foundIndex];
    workCell.contentView.subviews = tmpArray;
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the tableview with this white screen?

Comment: So it would appear that the white space is on the top part of the next cell, right?

Comment: Why don't you try to log the result of heightForRowAtIndexPath: and verify that it returns the right value for all of your cells?